# I want to add more data in tensorflow dataset ? my app build on android using java

Tags: javascript, java, android, tensorflow, dataset

I have already a dataset on object detection but there are only 1000 labels in it. so that's why its not accurate because there are only 1000 labels. Object like(phone,laptop,mouse etc ...)

its build-in dataset of TensorFlow lite. My question is very simple I want to add more labels and graphs in it.